# In Ruby, how do I use the value of a key from JSON as the key for a ruby hash that has it's values composed of two concatenated values?

Tags: ruby

I have JSON from an API of the form:

```
{  
"result":[  
  {  "sys_created_on":"2018-10-10",
     "number":"NUM54321", 
     "short_description":"This is a short description.",
     "other":"this is other stuff"
  },{
     "sys_created_on":"2018-10-12",
     "number":"NUM12345", 
     "short_description":"This is another short description.",
     "other":"more extra stuff"
  },{
     ... and so on for 1000's of lines
```

In Ruby, what I'd like to do, is create a structure that is of the form

```
{"sys_created_on(1)" => "number(1) + " | " + short_description(1)",  
 "sys_created_on(2)" => "number(2) + " | " + short_description(2)",
 "sys_created_on(3)" => "number(3) + " | " + short_description(3)",
 etc...
}
```

specifically, using the example data:

```
{"2018-10-10" => "NUM54321 | This is a short description.",
 "2018-10-12" => "NUM12345 | This is another short description.",
 etc...
}
```

That is ... use the value of a key from the JSON as the key for a ruby hash that has it's values composed of two concatenated values from the same JSON.

I ended up solving this problem using the following code:

```
my_list = result.each_with_object({}) do |item, hash|
   hash[item['sys_created_on']] = item['number'] + " | " + item['short_description']
end
```

That gave me what I needed in the way I needed it.

Comment: How do you determine which values to concatenate? And is the key supposed to be `value1`? Could you give an example with clear inputs and the output you'd like? Finally, why are you deconstructing the hash like this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide a fuller example to show what you want to do. Examples should be complete (no `...`, for example) and all inputs should be valid Ruby objects (strings should be in quotes, for example). That enables readers to test their code against your example to confirm that it provides the desired result. When giving examples please assign a variable to each input (e.g., `str = "..."` or `h = { ... }`) so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments. Always show the desired result (as you have) and make examples as concise as possible.

Comment: As the first step is obviously to create a hash from the JSON string, it would have been be simpler to begin with that hash and make no mention of JSON.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks! I updated it and ended up solving the problem while I was editing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'json'

json = '{ "result":[{ "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "keyN":"valueN" }] }'

h = JSON.parse(json)
  #=> {"result"=>[{"key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value2", "keyN"=>"valueN"}]}
arr = h["result"].first.values
  #=> ["value1", "value2", "valueN"]
{ arr.shift=>arr.reduce(:+) }
  #=> {"value1"=>"value2valueN"}
```

The first two statements can of course be chained:

```
arr = JSON.parse(json)["result"].first.values
  #=> ["value1", "value2", "valueN"]
```

Comment: Thanks -- this is close, but I need to be able to select certain keys by name and create the hash from those specific keys. I apologize if that wasn't clear. There are about 50 key:value pairs per item in result. I need to create a hash from where the hash key is the value of a json key called "sys_created_on" (a date) and map that to a hash value created from json key values "number" and "short_description" ... {"(value of) sys_created_on" => "(value of) number + (value of)short_description"} ... I think I see where you are going though and I'm working through some ideas now.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to incorporate the content of your comment. In general, clarifications of questions should be done by editing the question rather than elaborating in comments, in part because not all readers read all comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
  new_old = result.each_with_object({}) do |item, hash|
      hash[item['sys_created_on']] = item['number'] + " | " + 
      item['short_description']
  end
```

This iterates over the given collection passing each element and the given object to the block. Perfect for building hashes.